# xamarin azure push notifications - how to get Json values in xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin

I am passing http POST request to Azure web API. I am sending push notifications from Azure notification hub. So I am passing below values as json text.

```
{
"textMessage": "Hello World",
"action": "action_b",
"appName": "Order",
"parameters": ["WO=1123232, mystring=abc, show=false"]
```

}

Message is sending successfully. But I need to get **AppName** and **parameter** values when push notification received.  In xamarin forms i tried to get json body value like this.

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Config.BackendServiceEndpoint);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I am getting this error

StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=eb8046a771af187481bd962f4b2b59093d136d8cb9f93ea86e26e730ef047fb5;Path=/HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=myapi.azurewebsites.net Set-Cookie: ARRAffinitySameSite=eb8016a771af187481bd932f443b59093d134d8cb9f92ea86e26e780ef047fb2;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=myapi.azurewebsites.net
Date: Wed, 31 Mar 2021 10:32:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
}}

Comment: Why are you executing an HTTP request in order to get push notification values?  That is not how push notifications work.

Comment: I need to get some values with push notification. that need to use after user receive the notification. As example after user receive notification and click it i need to open a page. So I need to send that page name with my notification. I am trying to do it

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question.  You do not use an http request to receive a notification.  The OS delivers the notification to your app.  This process is extensively documented.

Comment: I am not using http to receive the notification.

Comment: I am using http in OnMessageReceived method. this call after push notification receive.

Comment: The json payload of the notification is included in the OnMessageReceived parameter